# How to create variables in data step and set to macro variable values

Tags: sas

I have a data step as follows.

```
    %macro do();
    select temp into :templist separated by "|" from Filenames ;
    select temp1 into :templist1 separated by "|" from Filenames ;

    %do i = 1 %to &count.;
          data sub;
              set sub;
               temp =%scan(&templist,&i,|);
               temp2 =%scan(&templist1,&i,|);
               %end
             run;
          proc append base= master data= sub;
          run;
    %end;
  %mend;
```

I want to create two new variables temp and temp2 and set them to macro variable values. I know how to do the reverse, that is, create a macro variable in the data step, but I was wondering how I create a new variable in the data step and set that variable to the value of a macro variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to create a new dataset with two variables `temp` and `temp2` so that i-th row contains i-th elements of macrovariables `&templist` and `&templist1`.
Then, you can do it in this way:

```
%let count=3;
%let templist=a|b|c;
%let templist1=x|y|z;


%macro loop;
%do i = 1 %to &count.;
    temp ="%scan(&templist,&i,|)";
    temp2 ="%scan(&templist1,&i,|)";
    output;
%end;
%mend loop;


data want;
    %loop
run;
```

You don't need to put into macro loop the entire DATA-step - only lines where you assign variables. BTW, you can't use `%DO-loop` per se - only inside a macro. 
And make notice, that `%SCAN` should be in double quotes, so that when macro-code executes and creates open code, on the right side of the assigning statements

`temp ="%scan(&templist,&i,|)";`

and

`temp2 ="%scan(&templist1,&i,|)";`

there would appear character expression (`"a"`, `"b"` etc , not `a`, `b` etc)